# MODEL_SPEC in Federated Learning (Using Tensorflow Federated Core)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I am trying to use Federated code to build my own federated learning algorithm. But I met one problem. In the official tutorial, it define the Model Spec like following:

> 

```
MODEL_SPEC = collections.OrderedDict(
            filter1 = tf.TensorSpec(shape=weights[0].shape, dtype=tf.float32),
            bias1 = tf.TensorSpec(shape=weights[1].shape, dtype=tf.float32),
            filter2 = tf.TensorSpec(shape=weights[2].shape, dtype=tf.float32),
            bias2 = tf.TensorSpec(shape=weights[3].shape, dtype=tf.float32),
            weight1 = tf.TensorSpec(shape=weights[4].shape, dtype=tf.float32),
            bias3 = tf.TensorSpec(shape=weights[5].shape, dtype=tf.float32)
        )
        MODEL_TYPE = tff.to_type(MODEL_SPEC)
```

I am wondering if it is required to input the model as an OrderedDict. Could I input the model as a trainable Keras model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, TFF can work with models defined using `tf.keras.Model` (the functional or sequential APIs, not the subclass API) using the [`tff.learning.from_keras_model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/from_keras_model) method.

This method is used in the [Federated Learning for Text Generation](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_text_generation) and [Building Your Own Federated Learning Algorithm](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/building_your_own_federated_learning_algorithm) tutorials.